# How to make last element of second level of menu to drop up?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have been trying this for almost 3 weeks now but haven't succeeded yet. I need help in tweaking a bit my drop down menu. I will try my best to make you understand what I'm looking for.

I have a horizontal menu on my blog and the second and third level elements drop down. Is there any way by which I can make the last element and its level elements to drop up instead of dropping down? I mean, look at the fourth category on my menu - CURRENT AFFAIRS. On mouse-hover, its second element is SPORTS. 
Again on mouse hover over SPORTS, cricket, tennis, badminton etc float to the right and drop down. 
What I wish for is to keep SPORTS at the bottom of CURRENT AFFAIRS list(and not second on the list), and its elements - Cricket, tennis, badminton etc to first float right (as they currently do) but then to drop up, instead of dropping down.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is this one - http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_pullup.html
When we hover over DEMOS, then on ACTIVE FOCUS, the elements flyout to right and then drop up. I am wishing for the same. 
I do not intend to have an entirely drop-up menu, instead I want only the last, bottom element in the list to fly out to right and then its level elements to drop up, like it happens with ACTIVE FOCUS elements.
Can someone guide me how to achieve that?

This is the current CSS of the menu -

```css
/* Horizontal Menu */
#menutop ul,#menutop li,#menutop span,#menutop a {margin:0;padding:0;
position:relative;}
#menutop {height:49px;background:#1a1b1f;width:auto;position: relative;}
#menutop:after,#menutop ul:after {content:&#39;&#39;;display:block;clear:both;}
#menutop a {background:#1a1b1f;color:#e0d4d4;display:inline-block;font-family:&#39;Oswald&#39;;font-size:15px;font-weight:300;line-height:49px;padding:0 20px;text-decoration:none;transition:all 0.3s ease;}
#menutop ul {list-style:none;}
#menutop > ul,#menutop > ul > li {float:left;}
#menutop > ul > li > a {color:#e0d4d4;font-size:15px;}
#menutop > ul > li.active > a {background:1a1b1f;color:#e0d4d4;}
#menutop > ul > li:hover > a {background:#2f82c3;color:#fff;}
#menutop .menu-sub {z-index:1;}
#menutop .menu-sub:hover > ul {display:block;}
#menutop .menu-sub ul {display:none;position:absolute;width:170px;top:100%;left:0;box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);border-radius:2px;}
#menutop .menu-sub ul li {margin-bottom:0px;}
#menutop .menu-sub ul li a {background:#236ea8;font-size:15px;display:block;line-height:120%;padding:10px;color:#f6f6f6;transition:all 0.3s ease;}
#menutop .menu-sub ul li:hover a {background:#459bb6;color:#fff;}
#menutop .menu-sub .menu-sub:hover > ul {display:block;}
#menutop .menu-sub .menu-sub ul {display:none;position:absolute;left:100%;top:0;}
#menutop .menu-sub .menu-sub ul li a {background:#459bb6;color:#fff;transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
#menutop .menu-sub .menu-sub ul li a:hover {background:#3d8ba4;color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing my previous answer for your exact problem...

here you go ..

```
#menutop .menu-sub ul li a{
position: relative;

}

#menutop .menu-sub .menu-sub ul{
position: absolute;
top: -75px;
}
```

This should work fine. . .

Comment: Yes, this time the sub-menus stacked upwards like I wanted to have. The only thing I have to do now is to move certain menu items to the bottom so that their sub-menus don't get cut off. Thanks a ton for taking time and solving my issue :) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the site you want to makee changes to.

Now Try This

```
#menutop {
    height: 49px;
    background: #1a1b1f;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: The trick is simple you make the li of parent ul relative, and the ul inside the li (i-e the child list) absolute and move it upward from bottom. 

you can do the same with the next ul child as well.

Comment: Thank you Geek for replying. I added the .menu ul ul piece to the CSS but it still didn't work. So I have reverted back to the original CSS. However I have now brought SPORTS to the bottom of the menu category CURRENT AFFAIRS. And I am updating my question with the current CSS part of the menu (the entire CSS part for the menu). Please have a look if something can be done.

Comment: Should it be .menu-sub ul ul { instead of .menu ul ul { ?

Comment: if you want the sub menus to move upwards too then yes.

Comment: Yeah, I would have gladly accepted your answer, I tried putting .menu-sub ul ul { too but even that also didn't work. Actually I want only the sub-menus to move upwards, not the entire menu, that too only the sub-menus of the last child of the list. Like, if you visit my website and mouse hover over CURRENT AFFAIRS, the last child element is SPORTS. I want the sub-menus of SPORTS to move upwards on mouse-hover, namely cricket, then above it tennis, then above it badminton, then above it hockey, then above it, other sports.